# Calculate $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}n^2x^{n-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

I have some struggles with this exercise. I need to find out $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2x^{n-1}$$ I know that the answer is $\frac{1+x}{(x-1)^3}  $ when $|x|<1$ $ $. And I need to solve it by using integration and derivatives. But when I do so I get the answer $\frac{1}{1-x}$...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fit $\sum{n^{2}x^{n}}$ into a generating function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662772/how-to-fit-sumn2xn-into-a-generating-function)

Comment: Not exact duplicate but the difference is only dividing by $x$ and @Gerry Myerson answer there is what you need i think...

Comment: This one is also similar [How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n^2a^{n-1}}=\frac{1+a}{(1-a)^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097997/how-to-prove-that-sum-n-1-inftyn2an-1-frac1a1-a3)

Comment: And this one [Calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2q^{n-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493519/calculate-sum-n-1-inftyn2qn-1) ... Quite a popular question :)

Comment: You can probably find several similar questions [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20n%5E2x%5E%7Bn-1%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^{n-1}=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}
$$